# Get Connection Information BlackBerry 10

Tags: wifi, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, internet-connection

I have a BB10 cascade application that needs to know if the device is connected to the internet with the wireless interface in a specific moment. I can't find any interesting information about this subject. Can anybody help me in this matter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this using the Bps tutorial provided by BlackBerry (https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/bps/bps_tutorial.html)

After some changes to the code, I achieved the results that I wanted. Thanks